# Assign different value to multiple select with same name with JQuery

Tags: jquery, select

Here is my concern, what is the best way to change value to select form with same name. Here is the code, I can't change the html stucture:

```
<div id="SelectTable">
    <div class="SelectClass">
        <label class="SelectLabel>Title</label>
        <div class="SelectOption>
            <select name="cat[]">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="SelectClass">
        <label class="SelectLabel>Title</label>
        <div class="SelectOption>
            <select name="cat[]">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="SelectClass">
        <label class="SelectLabel>Title</label>
        <div class="SelectOption>
            <select name="cat[]">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What is the best way to select them to assign different value (.val()) to each of them?

Thanks

Comment: Is there an alternative to naming each select the same? Kind of defeats the purpose of the attribute.

Comment: Explain more about what you're trying to achieve in the end... give a concrete example.

Comment: Thanks for your interest, @ManseUK got the right answer. The purpose was to loading each select one after another via ajax/jquery after one option is selected. Then pass the array by post method. It is a kind of a multiple select dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to pinpoint each `select` like this :

```
$('select[name="cat[]"]').eq(0).val(3);  // first select
$('select[name="cat[]"]').eq(1).val(2);  // second select
$('select[name="cat[]"]').eq(2).val(1);  // third select
```

`$('select[name="cat[]"]')` returns all of the matched elements (3 in your case) then `.eq()` is used to

> Reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/MCU2V/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select[name^="cat"]').each(function(index,element){
//do stuff to each individually.
element.val(index); //sets the val to the index of the element, which, you know, is useless
});
```

That should select every element with a name that starts with cat (your square brackets after the name scared me.) and then iterates through them for you to change their vals independently however.

Comment: I was looking to assign different value to each one of them. Your code, will apply same actions for each one of them. @ManseUK got the answer. Thanks anyway.